# Is Enumerable.ElementAt<TSource> O(1) for HashSet?

Tags: .net, time-complexity

Is the implementation in `HashSet.ElementAt` O(1) and if not, what is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's O(n). All of the extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>` are, by necessity O(n) (because the only thing that `IEnumerable<T>` can do is ... enumerate). Although, as pointed out in the comments, they do attempt to cast to an interface that can implement the operation faster (for example, `ElementAt` will try to cast to `IList<T>` in order to implement an O(1) operation). Not that that helps in the case of `HashSet<T>` which doesn't implement `IList<T>` anyway.

For `HashSet<T>` the concept of "ElementAt" doesn't really make sense anyway, because there is no "ordering" as such. You're basically just getting a random element.

Comment: Then a smarter thing would be to do a `ToArray` if you need to use ElementAt on a lot of rows? Is it never possible to get the "correct" order with a HasSet?

Comment: Yes, a single `ToArray` and then multiple "element at" (via the `[]` operator) would be much faster. There's no such thing as a "correct" order with a HashSet, since elements are not ordered in any meaningful way.

Comment: Right, however when I do this: { 2, 3, 4 } and initiate two HashSets with those, I do get the correct ordering when stepping through each element.

Comment: @Dean: Don't forget about the performance optimizations inside the `Enumerable` class for array and List<T> types. For these types some operations are in fact O(1).

Comment: @Filip: The ordering isn't random. The ordering will be exactly the same for those two instances, always. However, there are no guarantees that elements are stored in the same order you supply them. I expect that the results of your experiment are accidentally in that order. Also, the order might change from version to version.

Comment: @Filip: What you're seeing is a coincidence. Two sets with the *same* contents will have the *same* order, but if you add additional elements to the set, you'll likely find that the ordering changes, since the hashtable buckets will move around as the set grows.

Comment: @Steven, I see. Are there any other Sets that are Fast and supply `Overlaps`?

Comment: @Dean: Open Reflector and look at the `ElementAt`, `Where` and `Last` for instance. It is nice to see what they do. Of course these optimizations come at a cost for small collections.

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer is just plain wrong.  Lots of the IEnumerable<T> extension methods (including ElementAt) attempt casts to other types (often IList<T>) that allow faster behaviour than O(n) where possible.

Comment: @Will: That is exactly what we're discussing here in the comments ;-)

Comment: @Filip: What do you mean by 'Overlaps'?

Comment: @Steven, Just noticed `Intersects` however, I want to know if it Intersects with the Exact same order.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the underyling list type. Reflector shows that `Enumerable<T>.ElementAt(...)` tries to cast to an `IList<T>` first. In that case it would be O(1).

A query provider for example might return something that is an `IList<T>`. But chances are that if you apply any of the Linq operators, it will turn into an `IEnumerable<T>`, because they are built merely using different enumerators, and it will become O(n).

EDIT: I overread the `HashSet`. A `HashSet<T>` doesn't implement `IList<T>`, thus it is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

There is no `ElementAt` method in `HashSet` so you probably want to know the performance of the `Enumerable.ElementAt` method when used on an instance of `HashSet<T>`.

The `Enumerable.ElementAt` method has an optimization for types implementing `IList<T>`. In that case the performance is O(1). However, HashSet does not implement this interface, therefore, the performance is O(n).

Comment: @Steven, there is an ElementAt becuase HashSet derives from ICollection.

Comment: @Filip: `HashSet<T>` does derive from `ICollection<T>`, but `ICollection<T>` does not have an `ElementAt` method. `HashSet<T>` does not (at least in .NET 3.5sp1) contian an `ElementAt` method.

Comment: @Steven, I am using .NET 4.0 and ReSharper suggests me to use `ICollection<T>` where I want to take a `HashSet<T>`. Anyways, using `ToArray` speeded things up a lot.

Comment: @Filip: I'm not very familiar with .NET 4.0 but I'm absolutely sure that Microsoft didn't add any methods to `ICollection<T>` for that release (because this would be a severe breaking change). Resharper suggests you to use `ICollection` because all method calls you do on it are based on this interface or on extension methods on that interface or base interfaces (`IEnumerable<T>` in your case).

Comment: @Filip: Perhaps this discussion isn't very useful to you. You propably don't care where it is defined. You call it, it compiles, it works :-). Just don't formet you are calling an extension method.